# ListView dentro de uma CardView

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma dúvida, preciso fazer uma layout igual a esse do protótipo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse layout é dinâmico, o item que está na primeira linha (pai) pode possuir vários itens das linhas seguintes (filhos), todos esses itens são clicáveis que irão levar para uma tela com as suas respectivas informações.

Enfim, alguém pode me dizer qual seria a melhor maneira de implementar esses cardviews com as listas dentro?

Obrigado.